# Como puedo enviar o mantener una sesion de Microsoft abierta?

Tags: php, laravel, blade, microsoft

quiero tener una sesion abierta en todas las paginas que he creado, ya que cada que me cambio de pagina en mi sitio web la sesion se cierra y debo inicarla de nuevo, lo que necesito es crearla en mi index de laravel y que este abierta en todas mis demas paginas

la sesion es un login atraves de la validacion de microsoft

Comment: En la línea 24 de tu código... ¡No, espera! ¿Dónde está tu código? Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código relevante del login y de la sesión PHP.

Comment: jaja, que gracioso eres !!